# Json / PHP - Get status and replace the return

Tags: php, json

so I'm trying to get the status of a server, and the field that the status is in returns 'true/false' however, when I place it in PHP, to show the status of the server, it's simply saying "1" or "0," is there a way to check the response, so I can say something similar to
"If 0, return "Offline", if 1 return "Online", if 3 return "Unknown Status"?

```
function status($server) {
    $constructor = 'https://url.com/query/'.$server.'/info';
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($constructor), true);
    return $json['status'];
}
```

The code that's responsing 0 or 1 is;
    Status:

I'm very confused why it's returning 0 or 1 instead of true or false, but I'd also like to understand how I can replace the numbers with "Online" or "Offline"

Comment: Can you include an example of the JSON file you're requesting?

Comment: {
        "status": true,
        "hostname": "status.myserver.com"
    }
Also, I was incorrect, if the status returns false, it simply returns nothing in the PHP snippet

Comment: Thankyou, can you include that in your **question**, also how are you calling this function are you iterating though a list of servers and then echoing the status?

Comment: Also I'd just like to add it is returning 0 when false and 1 when true as that is the way to represent a boolean true or false

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
function status($server) {
    $constructor = 'https://url.com/query/'.$server.'/info';
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($constructor), true);
    return $json['status'] ? 'online' : 'offline';
}
```

I used the Ternary operator: [PHP Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

In PHP the following is true:

```
var_dump("0" == FALSE); // bool(true)
var_dump("1" == TRUE); // bool(true)
```

That's why "1" == TRUE

Comment: This would work but for code re usability and general sanity, you should return true or false and then output dependant on that result. say `echo status($server) ? "online" : "offline";`